# Regex to get decimal value in string

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

As I am a C# developer, I would accept C# answers as well.

Lets say I have this string: "R 560.00"

There is a Alpha character and a space with the decimal value.

We can also have the quotations on the string.

But what I want, is to only get the Decimal value in the string. All the other characters should be removed.

NOTE: The String.Replace does not work as far as I want, that is why I turn to Regex.

This is what I have tried:
fields(amountIdx) will contain the R560.00

```
Dim regex As New Regex("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim amount As String = regex.Replace(fields(amountIdx), "^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$")
```

But the amount reflects back as R 560.00. It does not remove the other characters.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How decimal? Would you accept a regex that emitted only decimal points and numbers? Obviously R 56.0.00 would pass; do you want that?

Comment: Why `Replace` instead of just `Match`?

Comment: What Jon said, and remove the ^ from the start of the regex (and from the end if you don't expect the decimal to be the last thing in the string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use

```
Regex.Replace("R500.12", "[^-?\d+\.]", ""))
```

Eg:  `MsgBox(Regex.Replace("R500.12", "[^-?\d+\.]", ""))`

It will return 500.12

Comment: I specifically said Regex. Did you see the LINQ version of VB? That's some really confusing stuff right there. I will mark your answer as correct, just change your Regular expression to: \d+\.?\d*

Comment: May i know what's your expected answer? Is it "R" or "500.12". If it's "R" then \d+\.?\d* will work and for "500.12" [^-?\d+\.] , this works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var resultArray = Regex.Split(input_string, @"[^0-9\.]+")
.Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");
```

Where (c=>...) is the lambda for dealing with each element of the array and c is an array element

Comment: Did you replaced with your's?

Comment: Yes, the amount coming in the "input_string" is: R 560.00

Comment: I only want the amount variable to have 560.00. Thats it. No R or any other character.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ hack to take the first decimal-y positive number in a string, where "decimal-y" is defined by a sequence of digits and dots:

```
string s = "R 560.00";
string decimalyNumber = new String(s.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c) || c != '.')
    .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.').ToArray());
```

It works by skipping over characters until it finds a digit/dot, then taking everything in the contiguous sequence of digits and dots. I would imagine the performance would not be that hot, but unless you've got millions of these to do in a short time...

---

Or, you can use Regex and simply match `[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?`, which is zero or more digits optionally followed by a dot and one or more digits (non-captured).

Comment: [0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)? did not work. but \d+\.?\d* does